# Spivak's Differential Geometry Vol1: Integrating forms (Polar coordinates)

Tags: differential-geometry

In Spivak's book of Differential Geometry Volume 1 Page 266 Corollary 8, there is an equality:

[image]

I tried opening the working out, but I still don't know why I have a the $(-1)^{n-1}$ factor.  I am giving the usual orientation to the product manifold.

The page about the question can be found here:

[image]

where the $\sigma'$ form is a an (n-1) form in $S^{n-1}$ given by $\sigma'(p)(v_1, \cdots, v_{n-1}) = \det(p,v_1, \cdots, v_{n-1})$.

Comment: Could you please explain what all the terms are in the formula? Not everyone will have the book at their disposal.

Answer (score 1):

The coefficient of $(-1)^{n-1}$ comes from interchanging the forms $du$ and $\sigma'$. Specifically,
$$\begin{aligned} \int_{S^{n-1}}g\sigma'&=\int_{S^{n-1}}\left(\int_0^1 u^{n-1}f(u\cdot p)du\right)\sigma'\\
&=\int_{S^{n-1}\times[0,1]}u^{n-1}f(u\cdot p)d\pi_2^*u\wedge\pi_1^*\sigma'\\
&=\int_{S^{n-1}\times[0,1]}h(p,u)d\pi_2^*u\wedge\pi_1^*\sigma'\\
&=(-1)^{n-1}\int_{S^{n-1}\times[0,1]}h(p,u)\pi_1^*\sigma'\wedge d\pi_2^*u
\end{aligned}$$
as claimed. The last equality comes from the fact that $\sigma'$ (and hence $\pi_1^*\sigma'$) is an $(n-1)$-form.

Comment: I am still confused.  I understand your working out but I still do not understand mine...  Can you see where I have an error? (link to image of my working out) http://postimg.org/image/ghfrg9jq1/

Comment: @SergioJulioChionAguirre When going from the third line starting with a big $\Sigma$ to the fourth line starting with a big $\Sigma$ , your $du$ moves past $dx^1\ldots dx^{n-1}$. This will cause a factor of $(-1)^{n-1}$ to pop out.

Comment: @SergioJulioChionAguirre On a separate note, the whole reason for developing the theory of differential forms is so you can suppress the notation for changing coordinate (i.e., you define forms so you never have to write the determinant of the change of coordinates matrix). So unless you're doing an explicit calculation, you should probably avoid going all the way back to definitions and instead use forms for their intended purpose, namely to make computations look simpler.

Comment: oh i thought I could do it because of Fubini's theorem.  Thanks for the answer!  First time with integrating forms.  I am following Spivak's book, hope I get used to it fast...

Comment: It has been a very long time, but I did the math from the very definition. I have no way to justify the $(-1)^{(n-1)}$. I just noticed that every "good" singular $(n-1)$-cube $c$ in $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$, induces a "good" singular $n$-cube $c\times\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}$ in $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}\times [0,1]$, and similarly any partition on unity on the sphere induces a natural one on the cilinder. The sign just does not appear, because when computing each term of the sum of integrals as an integral over $[0,1]^n$, Fubini allows to change the order of integration without introducing signs.

Comment: Also, the first equality makes little to no sense, as you seem to substitute $g$ by $g(p)$. The second equality does not seem to follow directly from the context of Chapter 8 of Spivak's book, especially not from his definition of integral, and again does not make sense, as you evaluate a form inside the integral, as if we were integrating on Euclidean spaces. In avoiding the definition, you seem to apply properties that are not proven along the chapter, maybe you took them from other context.

Comment: I think the mistake Spivak made, was assuming that the diffeomorphism $\phi$ from the punctured ball to the half-open cylinder always preserves orientation, and that is false for $n=2$, for example. This might be the solution to the $(-1)^{n-1}$ conundrum.